# Dataset interaction using Parallel Programming Library(TTask)

Tags: multithreading, delphi-xe7

The goal is:

- loop around dataset, seeking some specific data using a class instance;
- saving returned data on database;
- show updated data on screen.

However, it is occurring very freezing. "MyClass" has no memory leaking, high timeout, etc...

So my question is: what is wrong with the code I'm trying to implement, and what would be the best solution?

> PS: The crash only occurs with multithreading. If the same code is
>   used without multithreading, everything is ok.

```
var T: ITask;
begin

  FMyDataModule.DataSet.First;


T := TTask.Create(procedure
                        begin


  while not FMyDataModule.DataSet.Eof do begin

       //Do the job 
        try
            MyClass  :=  TMyClass.Create;
            MyClass.SearchAndSaveToDatabase; //IdHttpRequest
        finally
            MyClass.Free;
        end;


       //Update UI, go next dataset record
       TThread.Synchronize(nil,
          procedure()
          begin

            //Go next record and update on UI
            FMyDataModule.DataSet.RefreshRecord;
            FMyDataModule.DataSet.Next;

           end);


      end; //end while
      end);

      //Start the task
      T.Start;
```

Comment: Think of **one** car and four drivers going to drive with that car to different locations at nearly the same time. What will happen? The same happens to your single dataset with some threads working on it.

Comment: Loop is inside TTask procedure , so I'm creating a single thread in addition to the main thread , for the purpose: not freeze inteface. So I disagree with your metaphor. Am i wrong?

Comment: The whole database components are **not** threadsafe. If more than one thread is bound to them you will face a race condition. The dataset is bound to some UI controls and you are working on the same dataset instance inside a background thread. (Two drivers in one car)

Comment: I'm starting now with threads. What would be the proper way to make this code thread-safe ? I need instance all database  components inside ttask procedure ?